# Create a frustum knowing only two edges

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

You have a 3D frustum. Consider the smallest face the "near" and it's opposite the "far" face.

[image: Illustration]

The near and far faces are both perfect rectangles (not squares).

No face is axis-aligned.

The near and far faces are not necessarily parallel to one another.

You have only four known points, two of which (x1,y1,z1 and x2,y2,z2) compose the top left edge connecting the near and far face, and the other two (x3,y3,z3 and x4,y4,z4) which compose the bottom right edge connecting the near and far face.

edit: I forgot to draw in the Zs on the image, but this is in 3D.

what is the simplest solution to finding the other four points?

edit: the math doesn't have to be exact, just "good enough." This is being applied to a computer program to generate a frustum. the frustum doesn't have to be "perfect"

Update - One possible solution:

find a point on the far face between it's two known points. Do the same for the near face. take the two points generated consider it a line. use that line as an axis to rotate the original four known points 90 degrees. the result will be the points needed. The problem with this solution is that I will need a matrix or quaternion to do the rotation, I'm hoping there is simpler solution.

Comment: If it's a 3D frustum, you probably need the $z$-coordinates of the four points too. Anyway, how are you so sure that the solution is unique?

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot to add the z to the image and description, i'll fix that now. What do you mean "unique"? Conceptually, it seems there should be a mathematical solution to this.

Comment: I updated the post with better information as well as one possible solution, albeit one that I'm not completely happy with.

Comment: What I mean is that there can be lots of different frusta that have those vertices. Consider the analogous 2D problem in which two opposite vertices of a rectangle are known. You can draw many different rectangles having those points as vertices.

Comment: Okay, given the added constraint that the near and far faces are parallel, along with the two known vertices per face and knowing that far and near faces will each be rectangular, that leaves no wiggle room for the unknown vertices. With those constraints, there is only one correct solution.

Comment: Okay... I see what you're saying now. It's tough to visualize this all.